# flutter send PDF data to a printer

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, printing, wifi

I have succeeded in discovering and connecting to the printer using the `wifip2p` plugin.
I want to print a PDF file from a URL or Assets by sending it to the printer.

Please tell me how to print by sending PDF data to the printer after connecting the printer. Thanks for answering the question.

***serch print***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:wifip2p/wifip2p.dart';

class SearchIconButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const SearchIconButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Positioned(
          right: size.width * 0.02,
          bottom: size.height * 0.02,
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () async{
              try{
                await WifiP2P.discoverDevices();
              }on PlatformException{
                print('Error!');
              }
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.search),
          ),
        ),

      ],
    );
  }
}
```

***write print name***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:wifip2p/wifip2p.dart';

class WritePrintName extends StatelessWidget {
  const WritePrintName({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Future<void> conntectToDevice(int position) async{
    CircularProgressIndicator();
    try{
      await WifiP2P.connectToDevice(position);
    }on PlatformException{
      print('Error!');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Positioned(
      top: size.height * 0.1,
      child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: WifiP2P.peerListChangeEvent,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshot){
          if(snapshot.hasData){
            List<Container> list = [];
            for(int nIndex=0; nIndex<snapshot.data!.length; nIndex++){
              list.add(Container(
                width: size.width,
                height: size.height * 0.05,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    conntectToDevice(nIndex);
                  },
                  child: Text(snapshot.data![nIndex], textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                ),
              ));
            }
            return Column(children: list,);
          }
          return Container(
            width: size.width,
            height: size.height * 0.05,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child:Text(
              '검색된 프린터가 없습니다.',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ) ,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use Printing Pkg for this https://pub.dev/packages/printing

Comment: The printing plugin has an example that outputs pw.FlutterLogo() . Do you know how to change to my pdf here??

Comment: what do u want to change here ?

Comment: There is no problem with my source. It is normally connected to the printer. As you said, I used the printing plugin, but if you look at the example of the printing plugin, it creates a document through page.add. I would like to print a PDF that I already have.

Answer (score -3):

You can do that by installing [this](https://pub.dev/packages/printing) package:

Comment: I know this package. I use PDF.Page.add() to create a PDF, do you know how to print an existing PDF?

Comment: You just need to specify that you dont want to print but to save as pdf, when you select the printer you choose save as pdf and thats it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30708216)